# Format number using LaTeX notation in Python

Tags: python, formatting, latex

Using format strings in Python I can easily print a number in "scientific notation", e.g.

```
>> print '%g'%1e9
1e+09
```

What is the simplest way to format the number in LaTeX format, i.e. 1\times10^{+09}?

Comment: I don't think `1^{+09}` is quite the output you want, but anyway.

Comment: True, of course I meant 10^{+09}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [siunitx](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) LaTeX package solves this for you by allowing you to use the python float value directly without resorting to parsing the resulting string and turning it into valid LaTeX.

```
>>> print "\\num{{{0:.2g}}}".format(1e9)
\num{1e+09}
```

When the LaTeX document is compiled, the above code will be turned into 
[image]. As andybuckley points out in the comments, the plus sign might not be accepted by siunitx (I've not tested it), so it may be necessary to do a `.repace("+", "")` on the result.

If using `siunitx` is somehow off the table, write a custom function like this:

```
def latex_float(f):
    float_str = "{0:.2g}".format(f)
    if "e" in float_str:
        base, exponent = float_str.split("e")
        return r"{0} \times 10^{{{1}}}".format(base, int(exponent))
    else:
        return float_str
```

Testing:

```
>>> latex_float(1e9)
'1 \\times 10^{9}'
```

Comment: Nice solution! This does what's asked for, however it's not normal to include a + sign or leading zero in the exponent when formatting for mathematical correctness (cf. the siunitx output above). Also, due to the `\times` command it's a good idea to use a raw ("r") string. These can be done by replacing the first return with:
    parts = float_str.split("e");
    return r"{0} \times 10^{{{1}}}".format(parts[0], int(parts[1]))
(Hope that's understandable: SO doesn't code-format in comments!)

Comment: @andybuckley Thanks for the feedback! I've corrected my answer.

Comment: I'm also not sure what input siunitx handles, just that its _output_ is in the normal mathematical format without an explicit plus sign or leading 0 in the exponent. My bit of inline code in the comment above is (sadly) the most elegant way that I could think of to map a cast-to-int on the exponent... maybe there is something funky in itertools for such things but hopefully it's clear enough this way!

Comment: @andybuckley If we map both the exponent *and* the base to int (and there's no reason not to, as far as I know), we can make it more elegant. See above. :)

Comment: Erm, what happens to `latex_float(1.234e9) in that case? Or have I missed something obvious?! Obviously the mantissa-as-int works for the specific case of 1e9 :-)

Comment: @andybuckley It's me that has missed something obvious. I don't know what I was thinking. Corrected.

Comment: You can obtain a variable precision version by replacing the first two lines with `def latex_float(f,n):
    float_str = f"{{0:.{n}g}}".format(f)`

Answer (score 6):

Install [num2tex](https://github.com/AndrewChap/num2tex):

```
pip install num2tex
```

and use it as so:

```
>>> from num2tex import num2tex
>>> '{:.0e}'.format(num2tex(1e9))
'1 \\times 10^{9}'
```

`num2tex` inherits from `str` so the `format` function can be used in the same way.

You can also change the format of the exponent by using `num2tex.configure()` (adding this in response to @Matt's comment).

```
>>>from num2tex import num2tex
>>>from num2tex import configure as num2tex_configure
>>>num2tex_configure(exp_format='cdot')
>>>num2tex(1.3489e17)
'1.3489 \cdot 10^{17}'
>>>num2tex_configure(exp_format='parentheses')
'1.3489 (10^{17})'
```

As of now this is undocumented in the GitHub, I'll try to change this soon!

Disclaimer: After using (and upvoting) [Lauritz V. Thaulow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490292/format-number-using-latex-notation-in-python/13490601#13490601) for a while (for Jupyter, Matplotlib etc.) I thought it would be better for my workflow to write a simple Python module, so I created num2tex on [GitHub](https://github.com/AndrewChap/num2tex) and registered it on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/num2tex/).  I would love to get some feedback on how to make it more useful.

Comment: The package you offer and the examples on GitHub page are infinitely useful! Cheers mate. :)

Comment: Would be nice if you found some times to implement the \cdot 10^{p} option. :)

Comment: @Matt it already has this feature, I just hadn't documented it :)   See my edited answer for how to do it with cdot

Comment: I'm afraid there is a slight bug in the package. Quick example: `num2tex(100000,precision=1)` will yield $\times 10^5$, omitting the "1". it will happen for any $10^n$ with precision $\leq n+1$ (but not for $a.10^n$ if $a\neq 1$).

Answer (score 5):

You can write a `frexp10` function:

```
def frexp10(x):
    exp = int(math.floor(math.log10(abs(x))))
    return x / 10**exp, exp
```

Formatting in LaTeX style is then:

```
'{0}^{{{1:+03}}}'.format(*frexp10(-1.234e9))
```